# Оптимизации сортировки массива

Tags: c#

У меня есть два цикла "for". Когда записей ~100 они работают быстро, но когда записей больше 100000 скорость обработки может быть и час. Как я могу ускорить данный алгоритм?
Я думал разбить его на несколько параллельных потоков, но тогда программа может не увидеть соответствие в разных поток, соответственно повторы останутся.

```
 HashSet<IP> tbl = new HashSet<IP>();
                foreach (IP x in IPs)
                {
                    if (x.DataValid())
                        tbl.Add(x);
                }
                IPs.Clear();
                IPs.AddRange(tbl);
                for (int i = 0; i < IPs.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = IPs.Count - 1; j > i; j--)
                        if (IPs[i].ip.Equals(IPs[j].ip))
                            IPs.RemoveAt(j);
                    int status1 = 100 * i / IPs.Count;
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => LabelStatusValue.Text = status1 + "%");
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progress.Value = status1);
                }
```

Где IPs элемент класса IP:

```
class IP
{
    public string ip = "";
    public string port = "";
    public List<string> data = new List<string>();
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ip.GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool DataValid()
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress address;
        int port_number = -1;
        return System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out address)
                  && int.TryParse(port, out port_number)
                  && port_number > 0 && port_number < 65536;
    }
}
```

Нужно что-то сделать с двумя циклами "for". Думаю можно использовать `Distinct()` и с помощью LINQ получить индексы повторяющихся элементов, но у меня не хватает знаний, чтоб сделать это...

Comment: а не пробовали использовать List<IP>  и функции Linq?

Comment: @Monomax Я и использую List<IP>, а как это сделать в Linq не хватает знаний

Comment: `IPs = IPs.GrpoupBy(x=>x.ip).Select(x=>x.First()).ToArray();` ?

Comment: ну и обновлять UI в цикле на 100к операций - не оч хорошо, скорости это не прибавит.

Comment: Linq `Collection.Distinct()` удалить все повторения

Comment: @Санитариум для этого надо перегрузить `Equals`

Comment: @tym32167, или IEqualityComparer свой написать

Comment: @Grundy ну, `GetHashCode` уже перегружен, потому логичней тогда и `Equals` перегрузить, но так да, компарер тож вариант